# php if query works with wamp but not on live server

Tags: php, if-statement, cross-domain, wamp, wampserver

I'm using the code below to choose an image based on the domain.

the only difference between environments is wamp is running PHP 7 and my host 7.1 and I've been unable to get a copy of wamp with PHP 7.1 included.

on the live site, the end result is a blank white page with the PHP error on the 'else' line

I'm not sure if this is correct but after `$logo_img = "3_logo.svg"` if I add the semicolon you get a white page but without works just fine.

```
<?php
                    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
                    $logo_img = '';

                    if($host == "1.co.uk") {
                        $logo_img = "1_logo.svg"; 
                    }
                    else if($host == "2.co.uk") {
                        $logo_img = "2_logo.svg"; 
                    }
                    else($host == "3.co.uk") {
                        $logo_img = "3_logo.svg" //with semicolon errors - unexpected ';'
                    }



                    ?>
```

any help appreciated!!

UPDATE:

`var_dump ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` returns

Localhost

```
string 'localhost' (length=9)
```

Live site

```
string(23) "www.domain.co.uk"
```

Comment: You need a semicolon, without it you will have a parse error. So check your codes once again.

Comment: is `elseif` a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: code updated...

Comment: Have you verified that `$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']` contains what you think it does? Use `var_dump` to find out.

Comment: localhost returns as string 'localhost' (length=9) whereas the live site returns string(23) "www.domain.co.uk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix this 
here is syntax error

```
else($host == "3.co.uk") {
                        $logo_img = "3_logo.svg" //with semicolon errors - unexpected ';'
                    }
```

you need to write

```
elseif($host == "3.co.uk") {
                        $logo_img = "3_logo.svg";
                    }
else{ ..... }
```